# What happens if I clear data in download manager?

Tags: download-manager

What happens if I clear data in download manager? Will it delete all of my downloads?

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure what it does. Never really looked into it. But I just cleared data/cache for my download manager on my Nexus 6 and all my downloaded files are still there. Edit Just to clarify, the downloads are still there if you navigate to the folder with a file manager. However they no longer show up in the "Downloads" app.

Device: Nexus 6

Android Version: 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Clearing data in "Download Manager" is safe and does not have any affect on performance or anything related to android operating system. Clearing data just deletes extra files which were used once while updating your android system. Secondly, it will not delete all your downloads.

Answer (score -1):

this is an old question but the answer is no clear data from download manager will not delete any of your downloads